# Kubectl cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct

Tags: kubectl

Suddenly kubectl with gcloud is failing. kubectl was using an old build from 2021 but I upgraded it to see if that fixes the error.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials {hahaNotTellingYouMyClusterName} --zone us-central1-a --project {hahaNotTellingYouMyProjectName}
kubectl get ns
error: couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" }

kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.5", GitCommit:"5c99e2ac2ff9a3c549d9ca665e7bc05a3e18f07e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-16T08:38:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
error: unable to parse the server version: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

I tried:

0. Googling for the solution. All suggestions say check your .kube/config exists. A nonexistent config will produce this error.
1. Updated Docker. Still same error.
2. Verified ~/.kube/config exists after running gcloud get-credentials.
3. Verified ~/.kube/config is valid YAML
4. Verified ~/.kube/config points to the gcloud auth provider and the project I ran gcloud get-credentials for.

My kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ****
    server: ****
  name: ****
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ****
    user: ****
  name: ****
current-context: ****
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: ****
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: ****
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /Users/{myLocalMacUserName}/Tools/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2022-02-18T18:46:38Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

Comment: My hunch is that your (`kubectl`'s) attempts to access the server are failing, The `<` feels like the beginning of a regular HTTP error page.

Comment: Is the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` result in `~/.kube/config` consistent? Is the `server` correct? Does the `context` reference the correct `cluster` and `user`? Does the `auth` work correctly? i.e. do you get meaningful output from `${cmd-path} ${cmd-args}` i.e. `/Users/{myLocalMacUserName}/Tools/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud/config config-helper --format=json` should be valid JSON and include `access_token`.

Comment: Does your `gcloud` user have sufficient permission to the cluster?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @DazWilkin who asked if the "server" section is correct. In my case, "server" was an IP i.e. 1.2.3.4. I did a curl -k -v https://1.2.3.4 and found that it was returning a HTTP 302 Moved Temporarily error. I found that my company's internal SSO was broken and even though I was signed in, it was redirecting that 1.2.3.4 to SSO url.